# What could cause Google Colab to download a dataframe with different data from what is shown in code

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, google-colaboratory

I've been using Google Colab to filter data. I have a 2,028,011 rows long dataframe with 85 columns containing data about . What Im trying to do is filtering each person's parent's nationality to find which aren't from Mexico. Most of them have the same nationality (Mexico = 223) so im deleting such rows. For some reason certain 223 values are strings and some are numbers so I decided to filter them by every possible option [223, 223.0, "223", "223.0"]. I managed to filter my data and I end up with 1377 rows which sounds right because there should be very few non Mexican parents. The thing is that when I try to download such dataframe with 1377 rows as a csv, the csv that is downloaded has 18,817 rows and contains columns with 223 values which aren't present in the dataframe that appears on Google Colab. I've downloaded csvs from colab and never had this issue before, I really don't know what could be causing it because it looks and works fine online but after downloading it, it is a completely different dataframe. I'll add 2 pictures, one showing the printed dataframe on colab and one of the csv that is downloaded with 18,817 rows.
Sadly I can't provide data due to certain politics from the ones who provided the data. Im mainly trying to see if anyone has experienced anything similar to this.

```
    from google.colab import files
    newPrintable = pd.DataFrame()

    for index, row in printableNacimientos.iterrows():
      if ((row.PA_NACIONALIDAD != 223 and row.PA_NACIONALIDAD != "223" and row.PA_NACIONALIDAD != 
    "223.0" and row.PA_NACIONALIDAD != 223.0) or (row.MA_NACIONALIDAD != 223 and 
    row.MA_NACIONALIDAD != "223" and row.MA_NACIONALIDAD != "223.0" and row.MA_NACIONALIDAD != 
    223.0)):
        newPrintable = newPrintable.append(row)

    newPrintable.to_csv('newPrintable.csv', index=False, sep="|", na_rep=r'\N')
    files.download('newPrintable.csv')

    print(newPrintable)
```

[Result after printing my dataframe. It shows 1377 rows]

[image: 1]

[Last line of the downloaded csv]

[image: 2]

Comment: If you expect the columns to be numeric, then you should change the datatype to int64.  Then you can skip your loop and do `new = printable[printable.PA_NACIONALIDAD != 223]`.

Comment: @TimRoberts Hi Tim I'll make them the same type, still I tried filtering them in the same way you did by using both colums PA.NACIONALIDAD and MA_NACIONALIDAD and then joining them but the same thing happened, more rows are downloaded.

Comment: The last line of the downloaded CSV looks right, doesn't it?  It has 1978-07-24.